# Web-scraping in Python with BeautifulSoup - download file by clicking on button

Tags: python, web-scraping, download

I'm trying to automate the download of some data from a website that are represented in the chart (https://www.cboe.com/us/indices/dashboard/vxtlt/). I use BeautifulSoup but the function .find() or .findAll() are not able to find the file in the HTML code. (class = "Button__StyledButton-sc-1tdgwi0-2 jrAJxm")

In addition if I print the whole HTML response, I do not see the segment with the download link. Do anyone know what are the reason for this? Should I use another package, such as Selenium to click on a page.

Goal: To download the csv file with time serie data.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# URL of the website

url = 'https://www.cboe.com/us/indices/dashboard/vxtlt/'

# Send a GET request to the website

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# try

download_link = soup.find('a', class\_='Button__StyledButton-sc-1tdgwi0-2') # output None
download_link = soup.find('a', class\_='Button__StyledButton-sc-1tdgwi0-2 jrAJxm') # output None
print(download_link)

# when I try the html code I do not find the segment of the code with the file

print(soup.prettify)
```

Answer (score 1):

The data for the chart is from external URL. To get the chart data into a dataframe you can use next example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://cdn.cboe.com/api/global/delayed_quotes/charts/historical/_VXTLT.json'

df = pd.DataFrame(requests.get(url).json()['data'])
print(df.head())
```

Prints:

```
         date volume       open       high        low      close
0  2004-01-02    0.0  12.370000  12.370000  12.370000  12.370000
1  2004-01-05    0.0  12.990000  12.990000  12.990000  12.990000
2  2004-01-06    0.0  12.020000  12.020000  12.020000  12.020000
3  2004-01-07    0.0  11.030000  11.030000  11.030000  11.030000
4  2004-01-08    0.0  11.370000  11.370000  11.370000  11.370000
```

---

To save it as CSV you can then do (for example):

```
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Just in case, an alternative could be `pd.DataFrame(list(pd.read_json(url)['data']))` so you would also skip the `requests` part.

Comment: Thank you! This works for me. It is a good workaround.

Comment: @Andrej Kesely, can you find the API for this URL : https://www.cboe.com/delayed_quotes/envx/quote_table.
I tried to find the API but i think they are hiding it.